# Update Values in table with same id

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 Tables

1. LaminationTitle**

[image: Lamination Title table]

2. LaminationTitleRelation

[image]

3. Papertypemaster

[image]

I Want to update Values of"LaminationTitleRelation" table which comes from CheckboxList... Below is my Update Form....
Lamination Title in Below form Updated in  LaminationTitle Table, where as
Checkbox List Items should Update in LaminationTitleRelation Table

[image]

Note: if "Papertypeid" in LaminationTitleRelation and Items Checked are different then it should be add.

Plz help me

Comment: So this is what you 'want to do'? But where is 'what you have done' so far?

Comment: hi jeff thanx for reply....... i use different way to solve this problem...instead of updating records which is more difficult..... i directly remove/delete the records already in table and fire insert query on success of delete query....if the delete query returns TRUE insert will fire and all new records will add in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
query = "Create Table #PaperTypeMapping(LaminationTitleId int, PaperTypeId int)";

//For each value of Paper Type Id you will need to insert a row 
query = "Insert Into #PaperTypeMapping(LaminationTitleId, PaperTypeId) Values(@laminationId, @paperTypeId)";

//Update existing values
query = "Update OldMapping Set OldMapping.ActiveStatus = 1 FROM LaminationTitleRelation OldMapping Inner join #PapertTypeMapping NewMapping ON OldMapping.LamTitleId = NewMapping.LaminationTitleId and OldMapping.PaperTypeId = NewMapping.PaperTypeId"

//Insert new values
query = "Insert into LaminationTitleRelation(lamTitleId, PapertTypeId, ActiveStatus) Select LaminationTitleId, PapertTYpeId, 1 From #PaperTypeMapping NewMapping where NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM LaminationTitleRelation OldMapping WHERE OldMapping.LamTitleId = NewMapping.LaminationTitleId and OldMapping.PaperTypeId = NewMapping.PaperTypeId)";
```

or alternatively you can use the following link a built in utility by MS SQL [Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb510625.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DB = new DBFunctions();
        string vItems = mGetSelectedItems();
        string vQuery = "Update laminationtitle Set title='" + txtLaminationTitle.Text + "',laminationtypeid='" + ddlProductType.SelectedValue + "' where laminationid='" + Request.QueryString["laminationid"] + "'";
        int x = DB.SetData(vQuery);
        DataTable dSelect = new DataTable();
        DataTable dAll = new DataTable();
        DB = new DBFunctions();
        DB1 = new DBFunctions();
        if (x > 0) {
            int y = DB.SetData("delete from laminationtitlepapertyperelation where lamtitleid=" + Request.QueryString["laminationid"]);
            if (y > 0) {
                string[] values = vItems.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
                    vQuery = "insert into laminationtitlepapertyperelation(lamtitleid, papertypeid, activestatus)VALUES('" + Request.QueryString["laminationid"].ToString() + "','" + values[i] + "',1)";
                    DB.SetData(vQuery);
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), " Update Lamination Title", "alert('Lamination " + '"' + txtLaminationTitle.Text + '"' + " Title Updated Sucessfully');window.location='ManageLaminationTitle.aspx';", true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```